# Powershell Get a list of sites running under IIS on a remote Windows 2000 server?

Tags: iis, powershell

I have an old Windows 2000 server that is hosting several Web Sites. I would like to document the site information so i can move them to a new Windows 2008 R2 server.

I can get the info I want on a newer server by using the Get-Item IIS:\sites command.

Get-Item IIS:\Sites

So how do I get this info from the Old Win2K server using Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot enumerate websites from a Win2k box using the WebAdministration module, remote or not. However, there is always [WMI queries.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525265%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If you're interested in migration, I would look at [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) its very well documented.